# Regex to remove unescaped quotes from a CSV

Tags: regex, csv, escaping, quotes

I need to feed a CSV file into a database. For that I have to remove "wild" un-escaped quotes.

Following input structure is possible:

```
"aa";"bb";"cc";"dd";"ee"
"aa";"bb";"c "cc" c";"dd";"ee"
"aa";;"cc";"dd";"ee"
"aa";55;"cc";"dd";"ee"
```

The expression:

```
(?<!^|\"\;)\"(?!\;|$)
```

does work for #1 and #2 of the input examples but fails when there is an empty element (#3) or an unquoted numeric field (#4). Also see [this Rubular example](https://rubular.com/r/WkgKDEteVaBD2B)

Any pointer how to get these cases covered would be highly appreciated.

**Edit:**

Following @Wiktor Stribiżew advice, I'm now using

```
(^"|"$|";+"|";\d+;"|";|;")|"
```

this also covers some additional edge cases, I have identified in the input data, as shown [here](https://regex101.com/r/suDXQz/4)

Comment: Well this would match unescaped qoutes I guess `(?<!\\)"`, but not sure what is your expected output.

Comment: I need to keep the "text qualifier" quotes at the beginning and end of a column but get rid of quotes in the rest of a column

Comment: Judging by your requirements, you may use a regex replace method to search for `(^"|"$|";+"|";\d+;")|"` and replace with `$1` / `\1`. See https://regex101.com/r/suDXQz/1/

Comment: Rather than mucking around with the CSV, I'd suggest fixing whatever program that output this file, where you can probably modify the quoting behavior to make it less aggressive. Also, the 2nd line most probably contains a quote character in the 3rd column, and it's not properly escapes here.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Many thanks, works nicely. If you post it as an answer I can accept

Comment: @nhahtdh, I fully agree with you but unfortunately the data source is beyond my control

Comment: @Tom Good, I posted as an answer with explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution only meets your current requirements and is not a universal solution to fix quotes in CSV:

```
(^"|"$|";+"|";\d+;")|"
```

Replace with `$1` (or `\1`, depending on where you use this regex).

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/suDXQz/1/).

**Details**

- `(^"|"$|";+"|";\d+;")` - Group 1:

  - `^"|` - `"` at the start of the string, or
  - `"$|` - `"` at the end of the string, or
  - `";+"|` - `"`, 1+ `;` chars, and then `"`, or
  - `";\d+;"` - `";`, 1+ digits, then `;"`
- `|` - or
- `"` - a `"` char.